# MySQL query is working with MySQL command line but not MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using Google's algorithm for finding nearby locations based on coordinates in my PHP script:

```
if ($requestType == "closestPeers") {
    $clientsCoordinates = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT latest_latitude,latest_longitude FROM Assets WHERE username='{$username}'"));
    $longitude = $clientsCoordinates[0];
    $latitude = $clientsCoordinates[1];
    $miles = 0.0568182; /* 300 Feet, a bit larger than average Midtown Manhattan blocks */
    $closestUsersQuery = "SELECT *, 
                            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$latitude') ) * 
                            cos( radians( latest_latitude ) ) * 
                            cos( radians( latest_longitude ) - 
                            radians('$longitude') ) + 
                            sin( radians('$latitude') ) * 
                            sin( radians( latest_latitude ) ) ) ) 
                            AS distance FROM Assets HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5";
    $closestUsers = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($connection,$closestUsersQuery));
    foreach ($closestUsers as $nearbyUser) {
        $responseArray[$nearbyUser[1]] = $nearbyUser[4];
    }
} else if ($requestType == "cellImage") {
```

But the thing is that this query won't work for whatever reason. I can call `mysqli_num_rows()` on that `mysqli_query()` and I'll see `10`, but when I use this query I'm only given an empty array.

However, I could set `$closestUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM Assets"` I'm given an array with all rows which is obviously highly inefficient and certainly unsuitable for this particular application. I could also call the query provided by Google in MySQL's command line interface and I'm given exactly what I'm looking for -- The results from the database nearby.

These are the columns for my `Assets` table:
[image]

Comment: Should first $lat in query actually be $latitude? You should consider putting error handling around all database access code. You get no bonus points for cramming as many commands into a single line of code as possible.

Comment: Yes, it should! I'll edit that now.

Comment: I never new you could do 'HAVING' without 'GROUP BY' - Have you tried to put the whole thing in VIEW and query it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `0.0568182` miles were too few or something. If I were to set that a bit higher the query'd run but that doesn't add up because it returned results in MySQL command line at `0.0568182` miles. Thanks for reading and trying to help!